# How to clone micro SD card

Tags: windows, linux, clone, sd-card

I need to clone micro SD card, using Windows or Linux OS. SD card should be cloned as a whole volume, and not as partition. It may contains several partitions, some of them cannot be recognized by Windows/Linux. Basically, I want to make SD card image file, and then to insert another SD card media and copy this file to it, overriding everything that this media contains. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Linux you can use `dd` to do that.

`dd if=/dev/sdcard1 of=/dev/sdcard2` where `if` is the origin and `of` the destination SDs.

or if you want to take the image first and copy it to 2nd SD after:

```
dd if=/dev/sdcard1 of=~/sdimage 
dd if=~/sdimage of=/dev/sdcard2
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I am trying to do, but from some reason the second stage (image file to SD card) hangs after some time.

Comment: Are the SDs the same size? if not, the 2nd needs to be larger than 1st one. If not and  SD1 not 100% used, you can try resizing the filesystems and partitions there but that is another topic :)

Comment: Finally I managed to do this with dd, but it is necessary to unmount all SD card partitions before running dd.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/), which is a small Linux live distro which allows you to create drive images or to exactly copy one drive to another.

Answer (score 1):

Just use **dd for Windows** (http://www.chrysocome.net/dd).

Run CDM as Administrator:

```
dd --list
```

Check which device is your SD card. In my case it was: `\\?\Device\Harddisk1\Partition0`. `Partition0` refers to the whole disk, `Partition1` to the first partition, etc.

Copy whole SD card to an image file:

```
dd if=\\?\Device\Harddisk1\Partition0 of=my.img bs=1M --progress
```

Then insert the new card and write back image file to it:

```
dd if=my.img of=\\?\Device\Harddisk1\Partition0 bs=1M --progress
```

If you get an **access denied** error after writing couple of blocks, clean the partition table of the SD card before writing to it:

```
diskpart

DISKPART> list volume
DISKPART> select volume #
DISKPART> clean
DISKPART> exit
```

Answer (score -1):

I have used [WinImage](http://www.winimage.com/) to do this in the past in Windows.

Comment: Thanks. Can this program clone the whole media, and not only partition? Is this program free?

Comment: How have you used it? What are the steps to copy write an image to an SD card?

Comment: Winimage cannot create images of SD with multiple partitions, as it see each partition as its own drive.